# NamedPipeClientStream AccessViolation

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I came across an issue today where the constructor of the NamedPipeClientStream threw an AV.

After boiling this down to try and get a minimal repeatable example I found...

1. Create a new project in VS2013 Update 4 (Console will do) targeting .Net 3.5
2. Change main to look like this....

   ```
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "Global\\Turnips", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
       }
   ```
3. Run.
4. [image]

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? I've looked through the code in the ctor of the named pipe using IlSpy and I can't see any reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for creating a good repro, but this does not crash on my machine. Windows 7 x64. .NET 4.5.2 targeted to 3.5. This is evidence that your machine is hosed. What's the significance of that particular pipe name?

Comment: @usr Thanks for checking. Nothing in the pipe name, just what I was playing with at the time. I'll see if I can get a colleague to check on a different machine

Comment: Disable your anti-malware and try again.